# Connecting C# app with Oracle 10g: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, oracle10g

I am a beginner in working with databases. I am trying to access Oracle10g database from a c# application. But when I do so i get this error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

I'm using the following code:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=system;Password=goodbye;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open();
```

Is there an error in the connection string `oradb`?

Comment: The data source name afaik needs to be registered as a TNS name, it's just saying it doesn't know where your the database called ORCL is located.

Comment: @AmulGarg try with `Data Source =localhost:1521/orcl;User Id=system;Password=goodbye;`. *Disclaimer: this is from memory and I've only worked once with Oracle.*

Comment: Tried and got a new exception "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"

Comment: Thanks! I used the connection string "Data Source =localhost:1521/XE;User Id=system;Password=goodbye;" and it worked!

Comment: Apparently I needed to define ORCL instance in tnsnames.ora file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start the `Visual Studio`, open `View` menu + Server Explorer.

1. Right mouse click on `Data Connection` + `Add Connection` + Select `Oracle Database`
2. server Name : `localhost` or `name of your machine`, set username & password and click on Test Connection to verify the above parameters. Press OK if test is succeeds.

From properties windows you can obtain connection String and it should be look a like:

```
Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=scott;Password=***********;Unicode=True
```

Comment: When doing this up I get the same error message once I click Ok.

Comment: @AmulGarg - Start the Database server - From start menu Items (`Start Database`)

Comment: You can use `XE` instance name if you've oracle 10g express edition.

Comment: I have the same problem
Show me the same error in the project, while it does not appear in another project and I use the same machine and the same code @AVD

Comment: I have the same problem Show me the same error in the project, while it does not appear in another project and I use the same machine and the same code @amulous

Comment: I have some problem and I made your say It fix thanks. In additional the tool not give Password=XX; if you get error you can add password field.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is just stating that it can't find the database.

If you're running a local `Express Edition` database, you should be able to just use `XE` as an instance name, and everything should already be set up, otherwise you can most easily add it to `tnsnames.ora`.

To find the correct `tnsnames.ora` to change, you can try (from the command prompt)

```
tnsping ORCL
```

That will tell you which files Oracle is using to try to find the database. If `tnsping` is an unknown command, you may have to search for it and go to the correct place before running it.

One you found the correct `tnsnames.ora`, you need to add the instance `ORCL` to it. There should be an existing file with examples, the syntax of that file is too complex to answer here, if you need help, [Oracle has quite extensive documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/tnsnames.htm).

Comment: @AmulGarg If the answers helped, you should upvote and/or mark one of them as a solution. That will allow others to find solutions to their problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common oracle error. Simply put, it means that you have named the database you wish to be connected to and Oracle doesn’t know who the heck you’re talking about. I suggest 6 Steps to fix ORA-12154:

1. Check instance name has been entered correctly in tnsnames.ora.
2. There should be no control characters at the end of the instance or database name.
3. All paranthesis around the TNS entry should be properly terminated
4. Domain name entry in sqlnet.ora should not be conflicting with full database name.
5. If problem still persists, try to re-create TNS entry in tnsnames.ora.
6. At last you may add new entries using the SQL*Net Easy configuration utility.

More informations on oracle site or here : http://turfybot.free.fr/oracle/11g/errors/ORA-12154.html