# how to create connection string for oracle c#

Tags: c#, oracle

i am creating connection string for oracle in c#

below is my code

```
 OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.5 )(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));User Id=nTireoffice ;Password=nTireoffice;");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strSql = " select to_number (nvl(max(nvl(Region_ID ,0)),0)+1 ) as No from BO_REGION_MASTER ;";

        cn.Open();

        OracleDataAdapter objSda = new OracleDataAdapter(strSql, cn);

        objSda.Fill(dt);
        string s = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

its throwing exception  ORA-06413: Connection not open.

i am using windows 8 enterprises 64 bit os

thank u...

Comment: Your connection string looks correct, unless the server name or the database name  is incorrect . This can also be that you are mixing x86 and x64 assemblies? Are you using ODP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06413_connection_not_open.htm). (This is a very useful site for clues about most ORA errors.)

It sounds like it could be the folder your executable is in, or the actual name of your executable.

PS It would be useful if you could tell us the actual line the error occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the connection like this.

```
ora_cmd = new OracleCommand();
ora_con = new OracleConnection("Data Source={YOUR_HOST}:{YOUR_PORT}/{YOUR_DB};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={YOUR_ID};Password={YOUR_PASSWORD};Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=200;");
ora_cmd.Connection = ora_con;
ora_connect.Open();
```

Then use the ora_cmd to executes statements

Comment: error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: I did not face that problem but i think this should help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445201/connecting-c-sharp-app-with-oracle-10g-ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-con